# Check if the row checked in DataGridview exist in database

Tags: vb.net, datagridview

I have a `DatagridView` with a `Checkboxcolumn` My Goal here is to check if the Checked Row is already exist in the Database but my code does not give me the output I want. Whats wrong?

Here it is

```
 Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Dim conn As MySqlConnection = New MySqlConnection("datasource=localhost;database=operations;userid=root;password=admin1950;Convert Zero Datetime=True")
        conn.Open()
        Dim comm As MySqlCommand = New MySqlCommand()
        comm.Connection = conn
        Dim name As String
        For i As Integer = 0 To Me.DataGridView1.Rows.Count - 1 Step 1
            If Me.DataGridView1.Rows(i).Cells(0).Value = True Then
                name = Me.DataGridView1.Rows(i).Cells(1).Value
                comm.CommandText = "select ElecAssigned,ScheduleDate from assignments where ElecAssigned = '" & name & "' and ScheduleDate = @ScheduleDate"
                comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ScheduleDate", DateTimePicker1.Value)
                comm.ExecuteNonQuery()
                Dim reader As MySqlDataReader
                reader = comm.ExecuteReader
                If reader.HasRows Then
                    MsgBox("The persons that you Selected is also Scheduled Today.")
                End If
            End If
        Next
    End Sub
```

Here is the Scenario.

I  save a Data in the Table `assignments` and it looks like this.

[image]

and here is the Scenario in the Program

[image]

I checked a row in the `Datagridview` and select a Date in `DateTimePicker` which is the same in the my table there must be Message that will show saying `The selected Person is also Scheduled Today`

here is the code

```
 Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Dim connection As New MySqlConnection("datasource=localhost;database=operations;userid=root;password=admin1950;Convert Zero Datetime=True")
        Dim command As New MySqlCommand("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Assignments WHERE ElecAssigned = @ElecAssigned AND ScheduleDate = @ScheduleDate", connection)
        Dim parameter = command.Parameters.Add("@ElecAssigned", MySqlDbType.VarChar, 50)

        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ScheduleDate", DateTimePicker1.Value)

        connection.Open()

        For Each row As DataGridViewRow In Me.DataGridView1.Rows
            If CBool(row.Cells(0).Value) Then
                parameter.Value = CStr(row.Cells(1).Value)

                If CInt(command.ExecuteScalar()) > 0 Then
                    'Match found.

                Else
                    MsgBox("The Personnel(s) you Selected is also Scheduled Today")
                    'No match found.
                    'Save It
                End If
            End If
        Next
    End Sub
```

Regardless of how many I select the program will check if the persons selected is also checked.

Comment: Why did you create a parameter for scheduledate, but not name?

Comment: I do that to check the real value of `datetimepicker` because when i add it in the command it has an error saying Incorrect Date Format

Comment: The update look good. In this example, the IF condition would run 3 times (once for each row) passing in your date and the technician to the query. If the query returns > 0 then that technician is already assigned that date. Does the IF  > 0  run when debugging or does it skip to the else? Is scheduledate a datetime or just date?

Comment: Hi Sir, Sorry for not telling you that I updated it, TY Sir for always helping me. :)

Comment: The `scheduledate` is a date only

Answer (score 1, accepted):

E.g.

```
Dim connection As New MySqlConnection("connection string here")
Dim command As New MySqlCommand("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Assignments WHERE ElecAssigned = @ElecAssigned AND ScheduledDate = @ScheduledDate", connection)
Dim parameter = command.Parameters.Add("@ElecAssigned", MySqlDbType.VarChar, 50)

command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ScheduledDate", DateTimePicker1.Value.Date) 'Add a word Date to check only the Date

connection.Open()

For Each row As DataGridViewRow In Me.DataGridView1.Rows
    If CBool(row.Cell(0).Value) Then
        parameter.Value = CStr(row.Cells(1).Value)

        If CInt(command.ExecuteScalar()) > 0 Then
            'Match found.
        Else
            'No match found.
        End If
    End If
Next
```

You might require a few small adjustments but that's basically the way to go about it if you want to know individually for each checked row.

Comment: Wait Sir Let me Try this

Comment: TY for the Effort Sir its not working the code cant find the match

Comment: @PaulEdwardSanGabrielPagente did you try this? Update your post so we can see what you're doing within the IF statement. You need to close the connection when finished too.

Comment: Yes Sir, I will do it give me a moment and I will update it

Comment: If the code didn't find a match then there's no match to find. That would probably explain why your original code seemed not to work when you thought it should too. My best guess (and guess it must be) is that your `ScheduledDate` column contains just date and no time while the parameter value you're sending through contains a time.  If you want to use just date then change `DateTimePicker1.Value` to `DateTimePicker1.Value.Date`.

Comment: Please see my Edited Post. TY

Comment: @jmcilhinney I change the code to what you said and it works perfectly now.

Comment: So the issue was that you were using the wrong value for the scheduled date. The question is why didn't you see that for yourself?  Why didn't you actually check what value was being used?  Consider that as a lesson for next time.  ALWAYS check the data at run time to see whether it is what you think it is.

Comment: Im sorry sir. :( and TYSM for giving a hand.